Can not export the HAR file from mobile
I want to catch the HAR file from an Android device, and below are the steps :

open the developer options on the Android device.
Allow USB debugging.
Plug in the cable. (connect the computer with the device.)
open chrome://inspect/#devices.
click inspect and open the dialog.
Inspect icon
click the "Export HAR" in the dev tool.
Export har icon

Results :
click "export HAR" but nothing happens (the dialog of "Save as" doesn't appear )
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10g7XoHzCu5TEQ_cEGj6_EJFbaRf_Aroy/view?usp=sharing
I have tried :

Update Chrome to the latest version 125.0.6422.142.
update the Chrome app version.
restart the computer.

but the "export har " dialog does not appear when I click the icon.
Note.

but click the "import Har" the dialog will appear.
if I click "export har" on Chrome dev tools(Not via chrome://inspect/#devices.),the "save as" dialog will appear.
the same Android device via another computer, this issue didn't happen.


This may be caused by a corrupted Windows registry. For a test, just try the same once with Firefox and when the result is the same, you can be sure that this is the most likely cause. Without any guarantee, this procedure might be able to fix the issue: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/save-as-dialog-empty-grayed-out
